# Raspberry pi ssh connection with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Hello i am trying to connect my raspberry pi to ubuntu using ssh (ethernet cable).

```
 sudo ssh pi@ip address
```

and then I am asked to type in the password and when I do it says "premission denied, try again" and at the end "premission denied (publickey,password)",

I tried following a lot of different solution but nothing helps. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have two Computers. One is the raspberry pi, the second is the ubuntu machine. If both do have internet connection (actually they only need a local ip address), it is easy. Connecting them directly is possible but needs setup on both computers. If you connect both to your network (router/switch) it is easier.

You should be able by the following command:

```
ssh ubuntu_USERNAME@ubuntu_IP
```

You do not need to run ssh as superuser with root privileges (therefore no `sudo` needed) but you must use a username that exist on the ubuntu box!

Comment: Yes, I get your point, but the connection works anyways the only problem is it says my password is not correct when actually it is.

Comment: You could try out if you can log in from your ubuntu box to your ubuntu box. Try on the ubuntu box `ssh ubuntu_USERNAME@ubuntu_IP` or `ssh ubuntu_USERNAME@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

By sticking sudo in front of the command, the first password it will prompt for would be your local users one (to authenticate against the sudoers list). Once that password has been accepted, then the SSH command will run and then it will prompt for Pi's password.

As user7414723 said, you don't need to run ssh with raised rights.